# Show that $(1-b_1x -\ldots -b_px^p) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j x^j = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^j \left( a_j - \sum_{k=1}^{\min(j,p)} b_k a_{j-k} \right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^j
$$ 
be absolutely convergent, say, for $|x| \leq 1$. Further consider the polynomial 
$$
1-b_1x- b_2x^2-\ldots -b_px^p.
$$

> Why does it hold that
>   $$
> (1-b_1x -\ldots -b_px^p) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j x^j = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^j \left( a_j - \sum_{k=1}^{\min(j,p)} b_k a_{j-k} \right)
> $$
>   ?

I tried this way
$$
(1-b_1x-\ldots -b_px^p) \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j x^j = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^j - \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_1a_jx^{j+1}- \ldots -\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}b_p a_j x^{j+p} \\ = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jx^j - \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} b_1 a_{j-1} x^j - \ldots - \sum_{j=p}^{\infty} b_p a_{j-p} x^j
$$
and I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
&(1-b_1 x- \cdots -b_p x^p) \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j x^j \right)= \\
&(\color{red}{1}-\color{orange}{b_1 x}- \cdots -\color{blue}{b_p x^p}) \left( \cdots +\underbrace{\color{blue}{a_{j-p}}}_{\text{provided  } j>p } \color{blue}{x^{j-p}}+a_{j-p+1} x^{j-p+1}+\cdots+\color{orange}{a_{j-1}x^{j-1}} +\color{red}{a_j x^j} + \cdots\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} x^j \left(a_j - \sum_{k=1}^{ \min(j,p)} b_k a_{j-k} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How exactly do you get the last part?

Comment: If $j$ is less than $p$ then the blue term in the second bracket will not exist. We will only be able to match terms up to the $b_j x^j$ term.